# Is this a bug in NURBS-python when updating the control points?

Tags: python, nurbs

I used NURBS-python and found an interesting problem, and not sure this is done like this intentionally or it is simply a bug. I would like to introduce this with 2 codes.

The first one should output the same as the second one, while it is not. The first one successfully updated the control points of the NURBS curve and drawed a new curve,

The way to change the control points list influence the results.

```
import math
from geomdl import BSpline
from geomdl import NURBS
from geomdl import fitting
from geomdl import convert
from geomdl.visualization import VisMPL

P1=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [1, -1], [0, -1], [0, 0]]
Degree=3
CPN=5

P2=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 0], [2, -1], [0, -1], [0, 0]]
CP=[[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0], [1, -2], [0, 0]]

c1=NURBS.Curve()
c1.degree=Degree
c1.ctrlpts=P1
c1.weights=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
c1.knotvector=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 1]

c1.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
c1.render()

c1.ctrlpts=P2
c1.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
c1.render()


c2=convert.bspline_to_nurbs(fitting.approximate_curve(P1, Degree, ctrlpts_size=CPN))

c2.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
c2.render()

c2.ctrlpts=CP

c2.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
c2.render()
```

while the second one simply update the control points, the curve itself didn't change at all.

```
import math
from geomdl import BSpline
from geomdl import NURBS
from geomdl import fitting
from geomdl import convert
from geomdl.visualization import VisMPL

P1=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [1, -1], [0, -1], [0, 0]]
Degree=3
CPN=5

P2=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 0], [2, -1], [0, -1], [0, 0]]
CP=[[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0], [1, -2], [0, 0]]

c1=NURBS.Curve()
c1.degree=Degree
c1.ctrlpts=P1
c1.weights=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
c1.knotvector=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 1]

c1.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
c1.render()


for i in range(len(P2)):
    c1.ctrlpts[i]=P2[i]
c1.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
c1.render()

c2=convert.bspline_to_nurbs(fitting.approximate_curve(P1, Degree, ctrlpts_size=CPN))

c2.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
c2.render()

for i in range(len(CP)):
    c2.ctrlpts[i]=CP[i]

c2.vis=VisMPL.VisCurve2D()
c2.render()
```

Please help out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Curve.ctrlpts` is a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties). When you access the getter, it returns the list of control points. Accessing the setter does a lot more, mostly consistency checking and necessary cleanups.

When `cpts = c1.ctrlpts` is called, `__get__` method of the property is called, reference of the list object that stores the control points inside the `Curve` instance is returned and assigned to `cpts` variable:

```
>>> cpts = c1.ctrlpts
>>> type(cpts)
<class 'list'>
```

When you loop through the list `cpts`, you actually loop through its reference in the `Curve` class instance. Since you are interacting with the list object directly, you don't access the `ctrlpts` setter, which actually does the cleanups by calling `Curve.reset()` method.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to override methods of the built-in classes (the classes defined on the API level).

```
>>> list.__getitem__ = my_getter_method
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'list'
```

As a result, triggering the `Curve.reset()` method when the underlying `list` object changes becomes a little bit complicated (but not impossible).

The best and the safest way to set control points is using the setter method of the property:

```
my_ctrlpts = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
c1.ctrlpts = my_ctrlpts
```

If you would like to use the for loop, then you need to call the reset method manually:

```
for i in range(len(P2)):
    c1.ctrlpts[i]=P2[i]
c1.reset(evalpts=True)
```

Note: I am the author of NURBS-Python (geomdl)